# Need python dictionary to act like deque (have maximum length)

Tags: python, python-3.6

Is there any builtin (or very simple) method of having a python dictionary work in a similar fashion as deque.

I need it to have a maximum size, and when new keys are added, if the maximum length is reached then the key added first is deleted. It shouldn't be too difficult to implement as a custom class, but using builtins is always prefered.

I am using Python 3.6 if that is of any help.

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Comment: I disagree that “using builtins is always prefered.” Yours seems like the perfect use case for a custom class that is composed of builtins. If you try to do it without a custom class, you’ll be fighting the standard library the whole way.

Comment: Hristov: I've started to implement a custom class that contains two deques (one for the keys and one for the values) where I overload the getitem, len, contains and iter function, but I was hoping for a builtin datastructure.

Comment: ndmeiri: Ok, I guess I'll finish my custom class then

Comment: You can easily subclass `dict` (or variant) to achieve this. If you come up with a solution not already posted, do answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like a variant of `OrderedDict`.

```
class FixSizeOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, max=0, **kwargs):
        self._max = max
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        if self._max > 0:
            if len(self) > self._max:
                self.popitem(False)
```

Comment: This is so much better than what I had started doing, thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice! One comment is that you instead of using `max`, rename it to `maxlen`. Using the reserved Python keyword `max` here might accidentally override the default behaviour.

Comment: for `python2` user, use `super(FixSizeOrderedDict, self).__init__` and `super(FixSizeOrderedDict, self).__setitem__` instead.

Comment: Also, `maxlen = None` makes the intention clearer. And raise if user sets `maxlen` to < 1.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want a least recently used (LRU) cache.

The [functools.lru_cache decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) might be useful to you. If you want more control, then check out the package [pylru](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylru) or just google Python LRU cache.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, however, the code I'm writing should be used by people that has not used Python too much, so I'm going to use Sraw's solution.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Sraw's implementation, but updated to use the standard dict as well as avoiding keyword conflict on the max (now maxlen) parameter.

CPython 3.6 (released on Dec 23 2016) introduced insertion order in dict and from 3.7 it's been a guarantee. No CPython version which does NOT support this behaviour is supported anymore, it's time to update :-)

```
class FixSizedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, maxlen=0, **kwargs):
        self._maxlen = maxlen
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        if self._maxlen > 0:
            if len(self) > self._maxlen:
                self.pop(next(iter(self)))


fs_dict = FixSizedDict(maxlen=2)

fs_dict['a'] = 1
fs_dict['b'] = 2
print(fs_dict)

fs_dict['c'] = 3
print(fs_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2} 
{'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: This is better than `OrderedDict`, IMO. In fact, `OrderedDict` is just a subclass of `dict`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L78. So this solution will also be less-bloated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite straight-forward library called [CircularDict](https://pypi.org/project/circular-dict/) that implements this behaviour. Besides limiting the maximum amount of items the `dict` can store, it also allows setting memory usage limits.

To install:

```
pip install circular-dict
```

And then just:

```
from circular_dict import CircularDict

# Initialize a CircularDict with a maximum length of 3
my_dict = CircularDict(maxlen=3) # You could also set maxsize_bytes=8*1024 bytes
```

Then, you can use it just as a standard dict, and it will manage that circular-queue behaviour.

```
# Fill it with 4 items
my_dict['item1'] = 'value1'
my_dict['item2'] = 'value2'
my_dict['item3'] = 'value3'
# When adding this 4th item, the 1st one will be dropped
my_dict['item4'] = 'value4'
print(circ_dict)
```

Ouptut will look like.

```
{'item2': 'value2', 'item3': 'value3', 'item4': 'value4'}
```